# Do Android views, activity/windows and handlers created on main thread have separate message queues?

Tags: android, android-handler

My understanding is that since there is just one UI thread - there will be one UI message queue. Regardless of what approach we use

- `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post()`
- `View.post()`
- `View.getHandler().post()`
- `Activity.runOnUiThread()`

these runnables are added to the one UI message queue and executed serially.

If I am wrong, and there are multiple message queues for each view and each handler I create via code (attaching them all to UI thread), how does the UI thread decide the order of execution and which queue to prioritize?

Comment: You are right, there is only one message queue.

Comment: Thanks. So many ways to do the same thing - got me confused!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `MessageQueue`. Though there might be multiple `Looper`s, one per each thread.

`MessageQueue` is being synchronized upon each poll.

You can see implementation of [`Looper.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#L68):

```
static final ThreadLocal<Looper> sThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Looper>();
private static Looper sMainLooper;  // guarded by Looper.class

final MessageQueue mQueue;
```

Then [whenever queue is looped](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#L136) it might block:

```
Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
```

And [implementation of `MessageQueue#next()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java#L325) with `synchronized` approach.

**Note**, comments in the code are not made by me.